# How to import a map consisting of pictures

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, cartography

I want to built some sort of Fantasy Map with Quantum GIS.
The whole map is built out of 128x128 single pictures, 16384 in total. It should be a flat map.

How do I import these pictures and align them in a grid into QGIS?

Comment: You have pictures already made you want to overlay in QGIS with some spatial data? Then do you want to re-export the entire scene out as 128x128 tiles?

Comment: I have all the pictures already. Now i want to import them into qgis to create one giant map, if possible with a grid system.

Comment: How are the pictures named and how are they organized (folder structure)?

Comment: Folder Name 0-127 / Per Folder 128 Pictures /Folder 0 Pictures named: 0 0_001 0_002 0_003 ...  0_0126 0_127 Folder 1 Pictures named_ 1 1_001 1_002 1_003 ...  1_126  1_127 and so on. The arrangement is from top to bottom and from left to right.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the grid? Now it sounds like you just need an imagemagick script to tile everything together with a 1px gap or an actual grid overlay.

Comment: Well both would be great. First i need sth. to tile everything together (without a gap). Then i want to have a coordinate system for the whole map and the borders between the pictures should be the meridian and latitude.

Comment: OK new Infos, now i only need the coordinate system for this map. I stiched all the 16384 pics together to one giant 3Gb picture.